# Nested SAME elements. when :hover child, disable :hover parent CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

There is any way to control the :hover effect only on the child or its parent via css?
P.S. the elements are equal

I build a context-menu, but, in some case there is a possibility to nested elements.

this is the code

http://jsfiddle.net/bkoqv52e/3/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container row">
    <div class="col-md-6 content-section left"><!--parent-->
        <nav>nav</nav>
        <div class="content">content left
            <div class="content-section nested"><!--child-->
                <nav>nav</nav>
                <div class="content">content nested</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 content-section right">
        <nav>nav</nav>
        <div class="content">content-right</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width:100%;
    background:#eee;
    padding:30px;
  position: relative;
}
nav {
    height:30px;
    background:#999;
    display:none;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    margin-top:-30px;
}
.left {
    background:#ddd;
    height:300px;
    position: static;
}
.right {
    background:#ccc;
    height:200px;
    margin-top:100px;
    position: static;
}
.nested {
    width:150px;
    margin-top:100px;
    height:100px;
    background: #ff0000;
}
.content-section:hover > nav {
    display:block;
}
```

In this example, i would like to disappear the nav of content ".left" when i hover on the ".nested" (red) element.

Comment: To do this you would need to re-organise the HTML structure. You can't hide a parent element whilst keeping a child visible.

Comment: No, sorry, I would like to hide only the nav on the parent, not the entire element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

**update fiddle here**

http://jsfiddle.net/bkoqv52e/5/

```
$(".content-section").hover(
  function(){ // Mouse Over
   $(this).parents(".content-section").addClass("hide-menu");
  },
  function(){ // Mouse Out
    $(this).parents().removeClass("hide-menu");
  }
);
```